# Why my mathrm render latin modern math while symrm render XITS math? (I have redefined)

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

Why my mathrm render latin modern math while symrm render XITS math? (I have redefined)

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{bold-style=ISO}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\uglyepsilon\epsilon
    \renewcommand\epsilon{\varepsilon}
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\bm}{\symbf}
\renewcommand{\mathrm}{\symrm}

\let\sectiononly\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \sectiononly{#1}
    \let\sectiontitle\relax
    \newcommand{\sectiontitle}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        $\mathrm{e}\quad\symrm{e}$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `\unimathsetup{mathrm=sym}` to map mathrm to symrm. And why do you load the bm-Package if you plan to overwrite its command completly?

Comment: 1. I found that if I use `mathrm=sym` I cannot write `a_\mathrm{e}` but should be `a_{\mathrm{e}}`    2. because `\bm` is much shorter

Comment: 1. well the correct syntax is with braces. You can be lucky with some commands that they still work if you leave them out, but there is no garanty and it can change if some internal code is updated.  2. Sure, but then you don't need \usepackage{bm}, you are disabling its command anyway. Simply do `\newcommand{\bm}{\symbf}`